# MariaDb throws error on DELIMITER command

Tags: java, mysql

I have read all previous answers and still cannot understand why the code below will not work. I am running it from `JAVA 8` into `MariaDb 10.1` using the `Statement.execute` command. I suspect the Db connectors and have tried both the `MySql` and `MariaDb` Java connectors. It is the `DELIMITER` command that is causing the error. It works in a mysql terminal and any statements without 
`DELIMITER` will work fine from Java.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `procDeletePassword`(
IN _UniqueId int(11)
)
BEGIN
 DELETE FROM pword 
    WHERE unique_Id = _UniqueId AND _UniqueId NOT IN (SELECT app_pword_id from app) ;
 SET _UniqueId = ROW_COUNT();
 SELECT _UniqueId;
 END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Well then remove the delimiter statements.

Comment: Thanks FZ, I should have mentioned that my command is normally preceded by DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `procDeletePassword`;

Comment: The change in delimiters is necessary to prevent the ; in the procedure being interpreted as the end of the sql script. My solution is to break the sql script into 2, first to check and delete the old proc then create the new. A bigger problem arises if you export metadata using sqldump which always puts the delimiter clause in. These scripts will not run in my client.